# extraction of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, extract

I currently have [x for x in  if '' in x] for extraction but not sure what to add in

Answer (score 7):

You can use a list comprehension with a condition, e.g:

```
[country for country, colours in flag_colours.items() if len(colours) > 2]
```